# could not find driver error in Laravel 5.5

Tags: driver, laravel-5.5, laravel-seeding

I am facing below error while I am trying to run `php artisan db:seed`
. I ran `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` before.

[image]

**User.php**

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password',];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];
}
```

**Address.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'address','mobile_no','image','email'];

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(AddressessTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**UsersTableSeeder.php**

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class,10)->create();
    }
}
```

**AddressessTableSeeder.php**

```
class AddressessTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(\App\Address::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
            $u->users()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my model and seeder files.I could not find out why the error is coming out.

Comment: Try installing doctrine/dbal and see what you get. the MySql driver is standard in Laravel. Are your .env and config/database.php settings correctly set? Can the framework read data? What test environment did you set up?

Comment: Thanks @DimitriMostrey for your reply. 
Yes, My .env and config/database.php settings correctly set, because before this issue it was working properly. I didn't set up any test environment.

Comment: Strange. In you seeder, I presume you use DB::table('users')->insert(''username" => 'administrator', ....) and the database.php setting is 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), 

What happens if you try to create a record in php artisan tinker?

Comment: Thanks @DimitriMostrey for your reply. I added **Model** and **Seeder** files. I think those are helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: do you have the mysql PDO driver installed/enabled?  doesn't seem so

Comment: I didn't install any driver. How can I do that ?